# Javascript: Array length stays 0 when adding items

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have the following code and I check if a key exists in the array. if not I create it and then I push items in it. Everything works except that the length of the main array is always 0.

```
if(typeof this.markerList[this.lastClicked] === 'undefined'){
    this.markerList[this.lastClicked] = [];
}
this.markerList[this.lastClicked].push(marker);
```

result of a console.log:

[image]

Comment: looks like you are not using index based items... instead property key based assignment

Comment: Hm, you do not push to markerList, but to markerList[<key>]. Is that your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties) When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a
>   **valid array index** and that index is outside the current bounds of the
>   array, the engine will update the array's [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

The `length` property is therefore not updating as you're using keys rather than numberical indexes.

Since `Array` is also an `Object`, what you're doing is just attaching a property to it, which has no effect on `length` property whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects and can have properties.

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push(1);
myArray.push(2);

myArray["somekey"] = [];
```

A dump give :

[image]

The length property is related to the number of elements added with the `push` method or with a numeric index `array[x] =`

In `this.markerList` it seem that you didn't add any element in the array, only added properties.